# Multiple serde::Serialize implementations for custom structs

Tags: serialization, rust, serde

Disclaimer: I'm a beginner with rust!

Lets assume I have the following to structs and I want the default json serialization from the derived `Serialize` traits

```rust
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Address {
  zip:usize,
  street: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Person{
   name: String,
   age: usize,
   address: Address
}
```

In addition, I have implemented a custom `serde::Serializer` for a legacy format which takes any `Serialize` and internally forwards to the `serialize` methods when it encounters nested structs, enums, etc.

```rust
struct MySerializer {...}
impl Serializer for MySerializer {...}
```

Further, I defined a custom trait `MyFormat` that extends the `Serialize` trait and is supposed to work as a tag or something, i.e. if `MySerializer` encounters something that implements `MyFormat`, it should not use `Serialize`, but `MyFormat` instead.

```rust
trait MyFormat: Serialize {
 /// by default just use the normal Serialize trait method.
 fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        Serialize::serialize(&self, serializer)
    }
}

impl MyFormat for Address {
fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<<S as Serializer>::Ok, <S as Serializer>::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
       // this can actually look much more complicated, e.g. some additional mapping will be done here.
       serializer.serialize_some(&self.zip)?;
       serializer.serialize_some(&"some extra field only present in this format")?;
       serializer.serialize_some(&self.street)?
    }
}

impl MyFormat for Person {}
```

Now the problem is, when I use the custom serializer, I can, *on the most outer level* control whether to use the derived `Serialize`, however, the moment I descent into the structure, the `Serializer` trait expects `Serialize` types in the trait method specification which I cannot narrow down to `MyFormat`, as that would violate the trait.

In the above example `name` and `age` are ok, as the format for primitive types is identical, however, the nested `Address` might require to "inject" some additional fields if serialized to `MyFormat`.

I assume I just miss some paradigm that lets me do that with traits in rust. In C++ I could use template specialization or SFINAE. Is there anything in rust that can solve this kind of problem?

Kind regards,
Marti